# Expected value for the number of tries to draw the black ball from the bag

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

We have a bag with $4$ white balls and $1$ black ball. We are drawing balls without replacement. Find expected value for the number of tries to  draw the black ball from the bag.

---

*Progress.* The probability to draw a black ball from first trial is $1/5$. The problem is how to find the probability to draw black ball from $2$nd, $3$rd, $ \ldots, 5$th trial. When I know all this probabilities I can find expected value as $1\cdot(1/5) + 2 p_2 + \dots + 5 p_5$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of expectation value?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, from the wikipedia. The probability to draw a black ball from first tryal is 1/5. The problem is how to find the probability to draw black ball from 2nd, 3rd ... 5th tryal. When i know all this probabilities I can find expected value as 1*(1/5) + 2*p2 + ... + 5*p5

Comment: Exactly. Well, I invite you to answer your own question.

Comment: The probability is quite easy to figure out with this simple trick: Imagine you draw all the balls, one by one, and put them in a row, first to last. Then the black ball is equally likely to be in any if the five positions, which means that $p_1 = p_2 = p_3 =p_4 = p_5$.

Comment: @drhab My problem is when I compute $$\sum_{i=1}^{5} p_i$$ this sum is more than one and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. So I asked this question to look for valid solution and locate my mistake.

Comment: $p_2=\dfrac14\left(1-p_1\right)$ since you have four balls left, and $p_3=\dfrac13\left(1-p_1-p_2\right)$ and so on

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I got it. Should I leave this question as it is, if it is answered by commenters already?

Comment: You can leave it. The invitation to write your own answer still stands. Take your time for that, though.

Comment: @Arthur But when a black or a white ball has already been selected at the $ith$ step, then shouldn't the probability change?

Comment: There is no $i$th step. It's just mixing the balls and placing them all simultaneously in a row. If you insist on drawing the balls one by one, then sure, knowing what ball is drawn first affects the probabilities for the second ball. However, if you _don't_ check the first ball (close your eyes as you draw it, and put it away before opening your eyes), the second ball has probability 1/5 for being black. Alternately, removing a ball without looking at it can be seen as just another step in the mixing process, and the ball you actually look at is the first ball.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as if you will create a word with $4$ W's and $1$ B. For example $BWWWW$ or $WWWBW$ etc. How many such words can you create? Answer: $5$ and any such word is *equally likely*.

In other words: the probability that the black ball will be drawn at any place - not only the first - is equal to $1/5$. Not conditional probability, but probability. Do not get confused, that if you have drawn $4$ White balls then the probability of drawing the black ball in the fifth draw is $1$. This is the conditional probability. "A priori" it is equally likely that the black ball will be drawn at any given point from $1$ to $5$. So, $$E[X]=\frac{1}{5}\cdot 1+ \frac{1}{5}\cdot2+\ldots+\frac15\cdot 5=\frac15(1+2+3+4+5)=3 $$ (where $X$ denotes the number of trials).

Comment: But when a black or a white ball has already been selected at the ith step, then shouldn't the probability change?